# CentOS7.1 missing many perl rpms

Tags: perl, centos7

I just install a Centos7.1!
It seems to be missing soo many perl rpms.
Ex: perl-PerlIO-gz, perl-DBD-Sybase...

I can't seem to find them in any repo.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Contact the package maintainers?

Comment: Other than that and dependent on what your goal is: Install them via CPAN, possibly in a perlbrew environment.

Comment: What is the purpose of having those perl packages available? developing an application? requirements of a service?

Comment: I have a load of perl scripts that requires them. I'm wondering if they were built into EL7.

Comment: They were available on epel on el6.